# What is the name of this kind picture, a vertical cut of some object or terrain

Tags: single-word-requests

[image]

I think it's common in geology to show the different minerals and soils, and in construction to show how the elements are fastened, but I can't find the right term.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a **cross section**. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cross%20section):

> 1a : a cutting or piece of something cut off at right angles to an axis also : a representation of such a cutting
>
> ...
>
> 3 : a composite representation typifying the constituents of a thing in their relations

Here is a cross section of the Earth from [USGS](https://www.usgs.gov/media/images/earth-cross-section). Notice that the section looks as if the Earth were sliced along a vertical axis:

[image]